# Полный разбор использования типа varchar и text

Tags: sql, postgresql

В прошлом вопросе (Sergey Gornostaev) ответил:

> Но я бы рекомендовал всегда формировать как можно более строгую схему,
>   используя `varchar`, когда известна максимальная длина хранимой строки,
>   а `text` в тех случаях, когда неизвестна.

СУБД Postgresql. 
**Схема** - информация о базе данных, а также структуре и свойствах её таблиц.

Не очень понял формирование более "строгой схемы". Хотелось бы увидеть пример, чтобы понимать когда использовать `varchar` и когда использовать `text`. Потому что в книжках используется тип `text` и его рекомендуют только не описано почему, некоторые в компании говорят используй text и не парься. А знакомые разработчики говорят что нужно использовать `varchar` допустим для названия товара, а `text` для описание это же товара.

Comment: Предположим, вы создаёте таблицу `users`. В ней есть поле `email`. Можно использовать для него тип `text`, а можно `varchar(50)`. В первом случае схема ничего не говорит о размере ожидаемых данных и никак их не ограничивает. Как следствие, во-первых, ваши намерения плохо выражены, во-вторых, пользователь может запихать в это поле 4 гигабайта данных, в-третьих, если у СУБД появятся какие-то оптимизации в выборке данных фиксированного размера, использовать она их не сможет. И т.д. и т.п. Если используешь реляционную СУБД, формируй максимально конкретные и строгие схемы.

Comment: То есть у меня допустим таблица товаров (id, name, description,), (id serial primary, name varchar(50) - т.к знаю допустим все товары в магазине и знаю что выше 50 символов товара нет, поэтому ставлю 50. Дальше description и описание я не могу знать потому что оно может быть 200 символов, а может быть 10000 и поэтому я ставлю text ибо он никак не ограничивает, правильно?

Comment: Да, всё​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌ верно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А вот теперь вопрос, а зачем тогда поле description ставить text если я могу указать varchar и поставить 65 535 символов длину. Ну это вроде как максимальная длина varchar. Зная что свыше 65 тысяч символов в описании товара не будет, тогда тип text отпадает?

Comment: Релевантный ответ с точки зрения малого контрибьютора postgresql: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/980338/203622

Comment: Нет лимита в 65 тысяч символов. `create table f (s varchar(10000000));` - корректное ограничение числа символов.

Comment: @Мелкий Не очень понял, у varchar вы говорите 10 миллионов максимальное ограничение?

Comment: Я говорю что нет ограничения в 65 тысяч. Есть ли ограничение в принципе кроме как в 1ГБ данных - не знаю, нет сейчас возможности уточнить в коде.