# Varchar и char и применение в книгах

Tags: sql, postgresql

Читал по SQL книги и нашел вот такую таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
  prod_id    char(10)      NOT NULL ,
  vend_id    char(10)      NOT NULL ,
  prod_name  char(255)     NOT NULL ,
  prod_price decimal(8,2)  NOT NULL ,
  prod_desc  varchar(1000) NULL 
);
```

1) Почему `prod_id`, `vend_id`, `prod_name` не `varchar`, а `char`?
2) Почему prod_price decimal, а не numeric, вроде как numeric лучше же? 
Исправьте меня если не прав.

Как я знаю в PostgreSQL советуют varchar и text?
Проверьте правильно ли я сделал таблицу для СУБД PostgreSQL?

```
CREATE TABLE Products
    (
      prod_id    varchar(10)      NOT NULL ,
      vend_id    varchar(10)      NOT NULL ,
      prod_name  varchar(255)     NOT NULL ,
      prod_price numeric(8,2)     NOT NULL ,
      prod_desc  text             NULL 
    );
```

Comment: 1) Например, потому, что они не "до 10 символов", а "строго 10 символов". 2)  Это синонимы кагбэ...

Comment: @Akina numeric и decimal синонимы? Я читал документацию, встречал что они синонимы, но тогда зачем нам 1 из них? Если они идентично одинаковы? Или есть какие-то внутренние отличия?

Comment: @Akina 1) не очень понял от вас, вы имете ввиду что char(10) это всегда 10 символов, не больше и не меньше или что? Почему тогда с varchar нельзя это сделать?

Comment: Тип char является фиксированным и в случае строки меньшей длинны, дополняется пробелами (это надо учитывать). Тип varchar хранит строку так, как она есть и рядом сохраняя длинну строки. В итоге вы получаете небольшой перерасход ресурсов на получение актуальной длинны строки в varchar. В теории char быстрее, на практике это не имеет значения, пока данные не передаются по сети (тут уже выигрывает varchar). Ответ на ваш вопрос - потому что автор так захотел. Тут больше другой вопрос - зачем используется char для индентификторов id?

Comment: @AlexKrass `Тип varchar хранит строку так, как она есть и рядом сохраняя длинну строки.` - в postgresql это касается и char тоже. Потому что байты != символы. Ну и для toast машинерии и версионирования DDL из internals кухни.

Comment: @Мелкий я про абстрактный SQL в целом, для PostgreSQL вообще отдельная песня https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying.

Comment: @AlexKrass, так а стандарт и не описывает формат хранения на диске. Сказано - в char(10) должно быть ровно 10 символов. Как это хранить на диске развлекаются разработчики конкретной СУБД. Как small contributor я немного о том знаю https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980381/203622

Comment: @Мелкий ну это понятно.

Comment: @AlexKrass добавился

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Почему prod_price decimal, а не numeric, вроде как numeric лучше же?

Один тип не может быть лучше самого себя. Типа `decimal` не существует как такового, [это синоним](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) для `numeric`. Их два потому что таково требование стандарта SQL.

---

`char`, `varchar` и `text` - довольно близкие родственники. По требованию стандарта тип `char` всегда представляются фиксированного размера в символах независимо от объёма записанных данных. И уже только поэтому весьма ограниченной применимости - зачем тратить на `char(255)` всегда от 256 до 1024 байт (помните я сказал "фиксированного размера в символах"? Именно в символах, не в байтах на диске. На диске для postgresql это всё равно данные переменной длины) если вы туда запишете строку из десятка символов на 20 байт? Напрасный расход места и памяти. Некоторые другие СУБД могут получить преимущества при обработке данных фиксированной ширины, но для PostgreSQL это не применимо и `char` здесь будет медленнее `varchar` или `text`.

Это решение проектирования схемы базы данных. Например, не меньшее удивление вызывают текстовые `prod_id` и `vend_id`, отсутствие первичных и внешних ключей

Comment: Текстовые prod_id и vend_id тоже удивили, первичные и внешние ключи есть, просто они в отдельных запросах. И prod_id обычно как я вижу в таблице это BR0120 и тому подобное, а насчет ниже моей таблицы для PostgreSQL я правильно создал? Кстати чекните почту :)

Comment: `type modifier is not allowed for type "text"` у `text` нет модификаторов типа. Если хочется ограничить максимальную длину text (и меньше чем до поддерживаемого гигабайта) - то нужен check constraint

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд правильнее так:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
  prod_id    char(10)       NOT NULL ,
  vend_id    char(10)       NOT NULL ,
  prod_name  varchar(255)   NOT NULL ,
  prod_price decimal(8,4)   NOT NULL ,
  prod_desc  varchar(1000)  NULL 
);
```

- `char(10)` - потому что они ровно по 10 символов - похоже на ключи из других таблиц, надо бы еще foreign key прописать.
- `varchar` - потому что длина переменная.
- в некоторых СУБД `varchar` стоит заменить на `nvarchar`, т. к. поля могут содержать юникод. [Дополнительная информация.](//stackoverflow.com/q/1245217/4928642)
- `decimal(8,4)` - для денег традиционно используется 4 знака после запятой.
- про `numeric`/`decimal`, а также `text` не в курсе.

Comment: не существует такого типа данных как `nvarchar` в штатной поставке. Если вы не про postgresql - см. вопрос и теги. Если про postgresql - укажите используемые extension и/или create type/domain соответствующие запросы.

Comment: @Мелкий, исправил.

Comment: а в "других субд" - это каких? mysql? Алиас к varchar. sqlite? тоже алиас, но к text. Оракл? Тоже не знает такого если верить sqlfiddle. По-моему, nvarchar в одной только единственной ms sql и уместен.

Comment: А почему именно decimal(8,4)? Почему 4 именно, можно тут по подробнее?

Comment: @MikeMclaren, так исторически сложилось...