# Как субд хранят на диске данные переменной длины, например TEXT в postgresql?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, диск, хранилище

Как субд хранят на диске данные переменной длины, например TEXT в postgresql?

При записи данных на диск, мы не можем расширить их не передвинув данные, которые идут следом за искомыми. Меня заинтересовал вопрос, как субд хранят такие данные на диске, например строки переменной длины

Comment: Переменная длина на то и переменная, на неё выделено определенное количество памяти. Количество символов в строке "Комментарий" и "Справка" разное, но длина данных будет одна, так как в обоих случаях заполнятся до настроенной длины. Поправьте меня, если в чем-то не прав

Comment: @MaxDown, то-есть в любом случае там есть зарезервированный буфер?

Comment: Если судить [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/datatype-character), то у `TEXT` нет переменной длины. А так, возможно, Вы поймёте почитав, я в чем-то могу ошибаться

Comment: В разных СУБД используются разные способы. В Postgresql используется TOAST. [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/980381/184217), [2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage.html), [3](http://rachbelaid.com/introduction-to-postgres-physical-storage/), [4](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/TOAST)